# Disable WooCommerce action

Tags: actions, plugins, deactivation

I'm customizing a WooCommerce theme and am going to be moving the title. There is an action in `content-single-product.php` called:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

in the `woocommerce_hooks.php` file the title action is:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

I can easily comment this out and place the title function where I need to. I'd prefer to disable the title using a function in my themes `functions.php` file so I don't have to worry about modifying core files. What would the function be to disable this title action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5 );
```

You can read about it here: [`remove_action` Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I got problems removing an action just using remove_action (it is also stated within the documentation to use it not directly).

So I just remove it within the action itself, but with a very low priority.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', function () {
    remove_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_title', 5);
}, -1000);
```